# Remote check script license

Tags: php

I use a simple link to check license on remote server and get Success of Fail (1 for active and 0 for inactive) If 1, script run, if 0 script stop

```
http://licenseserver.com/check.php?key=test123
```

I make this call on each user login, but to speed up script i'm like to check license one time a week, and if license server is down try to check again for more 3 days, and if cannot contat server, script is turned off.

I believe correct is to have these check elements on database or on txt file (like last check, last attempt, etc), but user can edit parameters manually and bypass check.

There is a way to include this on encrypted file?

Comment: give up this approach, it never works, easy to defeat, slows things down, really gains nothing.

Comment: You can make it harder for users to bypass, but they can do it eventually!

Comment: @Dragon, Ioncube license.key maybe work better?

Comment: You cannot protect your code, you can only make it harder for people to break in. Zend and Ioncube are on of the most targeted ones on the market.

Comment: Killing the script is illegal ...

Comment: still easy to defeat, just route licenseserver.com to an internal script.

Comment: if Microsoft et al cant stop there software being stolen, you really have no hope, license it, or switch to a SAAS model, and live with the reality of the internet.

Comment: @djot What do you mean?

Comment: @Jeremy Banks Turning off a script (website/business) automatically like this.

Comment: @djot Why do you think that? My understanding is that license servers are not an uncommon way of authenticating licensed software. At work I am currently using software that requires a connection to a license server before it will start. This software is licensed from one of the major (many-billion-dollar) tech companies (can't say which due to NDA), and I assume their lawyers wouldn't let them do something that would get them in trouble like that.

Comment: I do not mean licensse servers and accepted terms and conditions if you use such a script/tool. Anyway, it could be illegal to shut down such scripts and most likely kill other parts/scripts with doing that also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks ALL for your answers.

For the moment I will proceed in this way:

1) Encrypt with Ioncube the script

2) Generate a license.key

3) Perform script installation on client server

On license.key i have setting up expiration date and hardware details.

Script have a cronjob.php wich download weekly an updated license.key from my server.

User can edit parameter (last check date for example) but if not update license.key software stop run.

I understand software piracy question, but this script is used in a big company and it's unprobable they unzend script.

In fact, stop run software is to regular receive payments from my client :-)

Big thanks to all.

Answer (score 3):

Not really. If the code is running on the customer's hardware then they can do whatever they want with it. This includes:

- running the code under a debugger and stepping through the instructions one by one, viewing all state at their leisure
- replacing PHP's functions (or a subset of them, for example those which can do network communications) with their own stubs that trace whatever is going on
- capturing the network communications and making a man-in-the-middle attack (for example they can interpose a proxy that always responds with an "all clear" message

You can certainly make it harder, but you can never win.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you just add your license checker in a few core files or just on admin area scripts rather than including it on each and every page? Have you tried http://www.phplicengine.com ?